# else executed with if inside of for

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a problem with 'if' executed together with 'else' when the value is equal to zero, the indentation seems fine so else is not part of for-else loop:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    if i == 0:
        print("i0 =", i)
    if i == 2:
        print("i2 =", i)
    else:
        print("else i=", i)


i0 = 0
else i= 0
else i= 1
i2 = 2
else i= 3
else i= 4
>>>
```

Comment: `if i == 2:` to `elif i == 2:`

Comment: 0 is not equal to 2 so else branch is being executed

Comment: You actually have 2 `if` blocks here. The first one which is alone (without any `else`) and the second one which does have an `else` clause. **Both** of them are ran in every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any problems. If you wanted those two ifs to form a single conditional branching, the second one should have been an `elif`. Right now, the loop body is comprised of two separate if statements and they are executed as: first, i is compared against zero; next again, i is compared against 2. So, when it is 0, the first if's then-block is triggered, and since it is not 2, the second if's else-block is triggered as well.

Did you actually mean

```
for i in range(0,5):
    if i == 0:
        print("i0 =", i)
    elif i == 2:
        print("i2 =", i)
    else:
        print("else i=", i)
```

?

Comment: that makes sense - I forgot about elif

Answer (score 0):

You're probably invalidating the first condition by the second "if" in the statement. I don't know python thus I'm not aware of any other conditional logic but it should be something like this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
if (i == 0 or i == 2):
    print("if i =", i)

else:
    print("else i=", i)
```